# Contents inside body not showing while using easy image collage

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a blog website in wordpress where i have added `easy-image-collage` plugin for gather images. at locally it was showing nice. But after uploaded to online those posts have [easy-image-college] shortcode were not showing. I have reinstalled the plugin but not got any result also searched in google but got nothing regarding this problem.

Can someone please suggest any link where can i get solution or any suggestions will better for me.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you move the site online? It sounds like the site move wasn't done correctly/fully... What process did you go through, in detail, to move the site?

Can you provide a link to the site so I can see the problem pages?

Comment: Provide screenshot of before and after. so we can get the idea

Comment: I got the problem, while transferring from local to online image paths have been changed and due to this all shortcode have no images as i have checked.. Thanks.